# How can I modify a flooring transition so that perfectly fits the two surfaces?

Tags: flooring

I have several instances where two different types of flooring are bordering one another and almost always they are not even (e.g. 1/4" offset, give or take).  A typical example is commercial flooring tiles on one side and regular ceramic tile on the other side or commercial flooring tile on one side and hardwood on the other.

Is it possible to modify a store-bought transition so that it exactly matches the offset?  E.g. take an aluminum top of the divider and then add a different number or padding/shimming strips on either side to reflect the offset.

Comment: Searching for "transition", "transition strip", "Hardwood transition", "flooring transition", "transition molding", "*floor type 1* to *floor type 2* transition", etc. Might yield some good results. You might also find [this question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/10127/33) useful.

Comment: I went through this in a few different areas in my house - wood to tile and wood to carpet.  If you have a pic I can probably help.

Comment: I think the direct answer to your question is "Yes, you can buy/modify/create transitions between different heights of flooring." As I suspect that is not really useful to you, I think you need to ask a more specific question, and perhaps exactly explain (dare I say: with pictures) what you tried that presumably didn't work and caused you to ask in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is. This most commonly occurs between rooms, so the "door threshold" is often tasked with the job. In most cases it simply adds a third level slightly above both - depending on the design it may overlap, or it may emerge vertically (overlap is better for lousy workmanship - emerging vertically requires that the flooring end or be cut precisely, or it looks sloppy.)

*An honest and substantial threshold looks 9 times better than a chintzy narrow piece of aluminum or plastic trim where someone chose to run two types of flooring together and not consider the transition; but that's an opinion (mine.)*

For your "calibrated transition" make it from wood as an overlap, and cut the rabbet on the high side deeper (think about it until that makes sense.)

The "vertical" type is most commonly seen as marble or granite thresholds anywhere from 2" to 6" or more wide. Cut out the appropriate section of floor **precisely**, plunk in some mortar, check the height, add or remove mortar, fine adjust with a rubber mallet, let the mortar set.