# Trim for floor transition where tile is LOWER than adjacent hardwood

Tags: tile, trim, transition

I have yet to find a product or a question addressing this. The issue is quite simple. I am installing a tile floor in the bathroom, and the finished tile floor at the doorway will sit significantly lower than the adjacent hardwood floor. This is mainly due to the fact that it is two layers of hardwood / laminate flooring.

There are lots of products from schluter to address the reverse (tile is higher), and plenty of wood trim options for when the two floors are in the same plane. However, I have yet to find the proper trim type to transition from the tile UP to the hardwood. I assume this must exist. What type of trim is this. I would prefer a metal type trim, but am unsure what the options are. Does this exist? What is it referred to as and where would it be found?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install transition molding between my new hardwood and existing tile floors?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/how-do-i-install-transition-molding-between-my-new-hardwood-and-existing-tile-fl)

Comment: Yes I believe that does coverall the scenarios. Thanks!